# Bold just label in lightning combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi i would like to bold JUST the label for the lightning combobox via LWC but not the entire picklist values.

This is my code below. I tried both css and also slds-class options but no luck..

```
    <lightning-combobox   
                name="Name"
                label="Name"
                placeholder="Select a Name"
                options={names}
                onchange={handleName}
                style="width:100px" 
                class="strong-text">
    </lightning-combobox>
```

css

```
.strong-text {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I just found a way to do it like this where i put variant ="label-hidden" and then make priority stand-alone . the only thing is the font size and color doesn't completely match the other labels on the page (there are radio options on the page too) 
``` 
<b>Priority</b>
 <lightning-combobox   
                name="Name"
                label="Name"
                placeholder="Select a Name"
                options={names}
                onchange={handleName}
                style="width:100px" 
                variant="label-hidden">
    </lightning-combobox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most simple variant you can modify the html file like this, using the form element component blueprint from [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#site-main-content)

```
<div>
    <label class="custom-combobox-label slds-form-element__label">Combobox label</label>
    <lightning-combobox label="Choose an option" options={options} onchange={handleSelection}
                variant="label-hidden">
    </lightning-combobox>
</div>
```

and the component's css file like this

```
.custom-combobox-label .slds-form-element__label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thinking for the future use and many different inputs on the page you can create a static resource file with styling overrides and load it in your component. Overriding css from the LWC component won't work because lightning-combobox is a separated component which is a child in a hierarchy compared to your component that hosts it, so LWC doesn't support styling inheritance from parent to child LWC.

Comment: Great thank you so much! this one works as well!! I appreciate the future use options as well

Comment: You're welcome @DigitalWoman